# Create a copy of a result row

Tags: php, arrays, associative

How can I copy an array that has other associative arrays in it?
I am talking about a result set returned from a `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

So say I have a structure like this...

```
connect
$result = query;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    array_push($static_row, $row); // here lies the problem

}
```

I would like to get that `$static_row` exactly as a copy of `$row`. Eventually I would like to put that query and while loop in a function, and simply return `$static_row`

As a reference, a `print_r` of `$row` looks like this

```
Array ( [key1] => value1 [key2] => value2 )
Array ( [key1] => value1 [key2] => value1 )
```

Thanks,
let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the form:

```
connect $result = query; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
   $rows[] = $row;
}
// now you have all the answers in an array of arrays, which you can return from a function
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but it looks like you have the copy assignment (which should work just like that) inside the loop. Maybe that is your problem.

Comment: oh my...excuse me...made a little boo boo there
this is what goes inside the while loop...
array_push($static_row, $row);

let me edit the thing above

Comment: you know what...nvm...I was making a very stupid mistake that I fixed just now...
it works like it should

Answer (score -1):

right from the [php doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

```
// Fetching all the results to array with one liner: 
$result = mysql_query(...); 
while(($resultArray[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) || array_pop($resultArray))
```